# How is iso accuracy line related to ROC curve

Tags: machine-learning, classification, roc, accuracy, auc

I have read many articles about ROC curve. Some specified a method to calculate the accuracy of a classifier using iso accuracy lines in a convex hull.

Some article examples:
http://mlwiki.org/index.php/ROC_Analysis
http://www0.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/ucacbbl/roc/

[image]

The question is: 
Most articles pointed out that, the intersection point between the accuracy line of a classifier (i.e C3) and the diagonal line can be used to determine the accuracy of that classifier, just like in the figure. But why? can anyone prove that for me?

In addition, given the ratio neg/pos I understood that this ratio is the slope of the accuracy line, but how about the intercept? It is not clear why they can construct a line just with a slope

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, the tangent of a 45 degree line is the ‘optimal’ threshold when sensitivity and specificity are equally weighted (often the default). If you change the weighting of sens/spec, you change the slope of the tangent line.

This is not the ‘accuracy’ of the classifier - that’s usually tied to the AUC (accuracy of an ideal observer).

I don’t think the ‘intercept’ of this tangent line has any real interpretation.

Comment: Why is a 45 degree line optimal?

Comment: @HEITZ The only "interpretation" is that as the intercept gets smaller accuracy also gets smaller. But the point where the isoaccuracy line cuts the true positive rate axis is not the accuracy.